# Запуск функции через нажатие на кнопку

Tags: функции, php

Подскажите, можно ли как-то запустить функцию на php через нажатие на кнопку?

Нашел вот такой код, но что-то он не работает.

```
<?php
  function dw($value){
    echo $value;
  }
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php wd('Привет!');?>
<button value="OK" onclick=""></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Вообще, нужно, чтобы было все по такому алгоритму:

1) заходит пользователь – проверка IP: если пользователь голосовал - переход к пункту 3; если нет – предложить нажать "да" или "нет";
 2) добавляется в файл IP;
 3) выводит результат всех голосов (сколько "да", сколько "нет").

Помогите реализовать, делаю бесплатный социальный проект на тему АТО.

Comment: Несколько советов:

- На 1 IP могут сидеть сотни, а то и тысячи пользователей.

- Если "накрутка" не имеет принципиального значения, то вешайте "куку", а далее при загрузке страницы проверяйте, если "кука" есть, то показываете результат, если нет, то предлагаете проголосовать.

- Если накрутка принципиальна, тогда предлагайте ввести емайл для голосования, а в нём код подтверждения + так же вешайте куку.

- Данные о голосах можно хранить в XML (если не хотите заморачиваться с базой) это удобно и работает из коробки (simple xml).

Comment: Почему бы не воспользоваться сервисом для голосований? [Например](http://www.rupoll.com/), или [вообще](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=сервис голосование сайт).